# Convert LibSVM output to vector of floats

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, libsvm

I need to form `HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector()` input.

I compute descriptors with openCV then use libSVM to get model file.
To form input i know that i need to get support vectors' values and elementwise mul them with alphas (then add -rho at the end), but **i don't get where to get these alphas**.

I have a list of SVs like:

```
1 1:-0.0434783 2:0.153846 3:0.194444 4:-0.353712 5:-0.45054
1 1:-0.2173916 2:-0.38461 3:0.222262 4:-0.676686 5:-0.78062
```

but where to get alphas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems things are clear now.
**Alphas are the first column** in my case.
Since i had all of them equal to -1 or 1 (dunno why) in my test model, i thought these were labels.

Anyway, here is my parser (but you need to leave only SVs in file):

```
std::ifstream ifs("cars_model.model");

    const int nsv = 90;
    const int nfeatures = 144;

    float rho = 12.5459;

    char ts[4000] = ""; // !

    std::vector<float> res(nfeatures,0);

    std::vector<float> alphas;

    Mat_<float> temp(nsv, nfeatures);

    int c = 0;

    std::cout << "Loading model file...\n";

    for (int i=0; i<nsv; i++) {

        float al = 0;
        ifs >> al;
        alphas.push_back(al);

        for (int j=0; j<nfeatures; j++) {

            float ind, s;
            char junk;

            ifs >> ind >> junk >> s;

            temp.at<float>(c, j) = s;

            //std::cout << f << ' ' << s << '\n';

        }

        c++;

    }

    ifs.close();

    std::cout << "Computing primal form...\n";

    for (int i=0; i<nsv; i++) {

        float alpha = alphas[i];

        for (int j=0; j<nfeatures; j++) {
            res[j] += (temp.at<float>(i,j) * alpha);
        }

    }

    //res.push_back(-rho);

    std::ofstream ofs("primal.txt");

    for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++)
        ofs << res[i] << ' ';

    ofs.close();
```

And you know, it works. You can set rho as threshold of the detector.

Answer (score 0):

But why do you want to classify this "by hand"? OpenCv  [has a classification routine](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) called `predict`, which uses found SVs' and alphas'

```
float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);
```

If you really want to do it by yourself you would not only need SVs and alphas but also a kernel function used for training and comput

```
SUM alpha_i K( support_vector_i , data_point ) - rho
```

I am not sure whether it is possible to extract alphas "by hand" without extending the SVM class, as one can see in the [sources](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/include/opencv2/ml.hpp) - alphas are stored in the `CvSVMDecisionFunc` structure:

```
struct CvSVMDecisionFunc
{
    double rho;
    int sv_count;
    double* alpha;
    int* sv_index;
};
```

while the only reference to this structure is in the `protected` section:

```
protected:

    (...)

    CvSVMDecisionFunc* decision_func;
```

From the source code of `svm.cpp` we can find, that it is only publically accesible through the `save` routine. So some "hack" would be to save the model and extract alphas from there (it will be located in the "Decision function" section, written in human readable format).

The simplest extracion technique seems to extent the `CvSVM` class and include method like

```
public:

    CvSVMDecisionFunc* get_decision_function() { return decision_func; }
```

## update

after clarification, that OP actually is trying to use externaly trained model in opencv - the easiest way is to convert the libsvm model crated by other method (libsvm, linearsvm etc.) into opencv compatible format and load it using `read` method

```
void CvSVM::read( CvFileStorage* fs, CvFileNode* svm_node )
```

[see source for more details](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp).

Comment: As i understood you can use .predict(), but you must provide it an already computed HOG for an exact same size image, as you trained CvSVM for, and this is inconvinient. In case you want to use routine that scans a given image, and returns an array of points, where it found an answer, you should use .detectMultiScale().

Comment: I do not really understand your comment. SVM will **always** require the exact same size of the input as one used in the training. It does not matter whether you extract alphas or use the predict method, it will work the same way.

Comment: Well, first of all, i decided not to use openCV for training, cause i found a lot of information, where people say that it is better to use svmlight or libsvm, so i can't use CvSVMDecisionFunc. The second thing i am talking about is that detectMultiScale() takes an image of ANY size, and does all the work for you, computing HOG at every point of image, and returns the matching points. Am i right?

Comment: So you can simply convert SVM model trained with libsvm or svmlight to the format that opencv can read using `read` method. While one can say, that its training procedure is somewhat malfunction(?) the classification process is implemented correctly so simply load the model from the external source and use the CvSVM object as the detector for your detectMultiScale().

Comment: Oh, thanks, i didn't know about .read(). By the way, i figured out some things now, so i'll post my parser code, and try your method, then compare results.