# Convert LibSVM output to vector of floats for OpenCV HoG setSVMDetector function (how to add rho)

Tags: c++, opencv, libsvm

The following topic has been very helpful for me to understand how to convert LibSVM output to OpenCV required vector of floats.

[Convert LibSVM output to vector of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089256/convert-libsvm-output-to-vector-of-floats)

Just one last step, how would I add rho to the detector? Simply add rho at the end of the vector of floats.

Comment: What is `rho`? Is it another `vector<float>`?

Comment: It is in the header of the LibSVM model file. Below is the explanation copied from LibSVM QA:

Comment: Q: The output of training C-SVM is like the following. What do they mean? 

optimization finished, #iter = 219 
nu = 0.431030 
obj = -100.877286, rho = 0.424632 
nSV = 132, nBSV = 107 
Total nSV = 132 
obj is the optimal objective value of the dual SVM problem. rho is the bias term in the decision function sgn(w^Tx - rho). nSV and nBSV are number of support vectors and bounded support vectors (i.e., alpha_i = C). nu-svm is a somewhat equivalent form of C-SVM where C is replaced by nu. nu simply shows the corresponding parameter. More details are in  libsvm document.

Answer (score 0):

That's fun to find my question was helpful for someone.

On topic:

Though in docs you can find info about addition `rho` as last element to primal form vector, i have tried it and it didn't work, moreover i find it weird to make primal form 1 element larger. In my case the solution was just to put `rho` as an argument in `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale` call.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I actually made it work by simply appending rho at the end of the vector. You may want to play with the sign of rho.